# Calling Cucumber from Ruby - Pass Watir Browser as object

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I'm looking to call Cucumber directly from a Ruby script using Cucumber::CLI::Main. Is there a way I can pass it a Watir::Browser object (or any other object for that matter) that I can reference in the env.rb? I'd like to reuse the browser object since I am getting errors from opening and closing too many browser windows. I'd rather not use a global object either.